# c# mvc3 load a different view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am checking if a user is authenticated, and need to direct to a different view if the user is not autheticated.

```
public ActionResult UserMaintenance()
{

  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    return View();
  }
  else
  {
    LogOn.View;   //// this is the area that needs help
  }
}
```

I would like to present the user the view to enter the login and password....

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RedirectToAction` to any action in any controller.

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
```

As you are using ASP.net MVC you can redirect it to `LogOn` action in `Account` controller

```
public ActionResult UserMaintenance()
{

  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    return View();
  }
  else
  {
    return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.98).aspx

and create a new controller method to handle the login.